# Unicorn is killed automatically

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I'm using unicorn in a staging environment (Ubuntu), when a build process is started unicorn is killed automatically with the following logs.

```
I, [2014-09-23T06:59:58.912673 #16717]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16720 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2014-09-23T06:59:58.913144 #16717]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16722 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2014-09-23T06:59:58.913464 #16717]  INFO -- : master complete
```

I'm unable to locate why this is error is happening.

Comment: I know nothing about Unicorn (never even heard of it) but +1 for the topic title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your unicorn server is gracefully shutdown by sending a SIGQUIT to the master process. In this case, the master process reaps all its worker processes after they have finished their current request  and then shuts down itself. Unicorn supports a couple more signals to trigger certain behaviour (e.g. adding or removing workers, reloading itself, ...). You can lean more about that at the [SIGNALS](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html) documentation of unicorn.

The SIGQUIT is probably caused by your deployment process which probably tries to reload/restart your unicorn but dies something strange. Generally, you should look at your unicorn init script or your deployment process for which signals are send (e.g by using the `kill` command).

Comment: Ah I see. I'm issuing a kill $(ps -ef | grep unicorn | awk '{if($8 == "unicorn" and $9 == "master") print $2}') so that my code changes are picked by unicorn. I guess I need to find another signal that reloads the code changes.

Comment: A generally accepted pattern (when using `preload_app true`) is to send a SIGUSR2 to the master and then send a separate SIGQUIT to the old workers once the new ones are confirmed up. If you google a bit, you'll find various unicorn configs which accomplish the SIGQUIT sending in an `after_fork` or `before_fork` hook.

Comment: I'm now doing a unicorn_pid=`cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
echo "Restarting Unicorn ($unicorn_pid)"
kill -HUP $unicorn_pid Thank you much you saved a lot of headache :)

Comment: Note that a SIGHUP will **not** reload your application code if you use `prelaod-app true`.